# Can we use snappy in standalone or do we need to use in conjunction with Hadoop?

Tags: flume, snappy

I want to use snappy to compress files with Java. I have downloaded the required native libraries and provided **java.library.path** to the folder containing **libsnappy.so.1.1.4** file. But still I am getting the following exception.

```
| ERROR | [SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor] | com.omnitracs.otda.dte.flume.sink.
hdfs.HDFSEventSink:process(463): process failed org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader.buildSupportsSnappy()Z
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader.buildSupportsSnappy()Z
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader.buildSupportsSnappy(Native Method) ~[hadoop-common-2.8.5.jar:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec.checkNativeCodeLoaded(SnappyCodec.java:63) ~[hadoop-common-2.8.5.jar:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec.getCompressorType(SnappyCodec.java:136) ~[hadoop-common-2.8.5.jar:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool.getCompressor(CodecPool.java:150) ~[hadoop-common-2.8.5.jar:?]
        at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSCompressedDataStream.open(HDFSCompressedDataStream.java:97) ~[flume-hdfs-sink-1.9.0.jar:1.9.0]
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the context of "standalone" here? It sounds quite vague (or misleading) because the exception is clearly coming from **`flume-hdfs-sink`**.

Comment: Yes, I am using it in flume, by standalone means I don't have any hadoop-client installed/setup on that machine, I have Jdk and Flume only and I have the hadoop*.jar files in the classpath. Then I have installed the snappy native library and set that folder to java.library.path.

Comment: Can you try adding it to your `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` rather than to `java.library.path`?

Comment: After setting $LD_LIBRARY_PATH also, I am getting the same exception. I have the following files: ```/usr/lib/libsnappy.so.1
/usr/lib/libsnappy.so.1.1.4
/usr/lib64/libsnappy.so.1
/usr/lib64/libsnappy.so.1.1.4``` And I set the /usr/lib64 to the LD library path.

Comment: What if you create a symlink `libsnappy.so -> libsnappy.so.1.1.4`. If that doesnt help then I'm afraid its time to verify you have other dependencies via `$ ldd -v libsnappy.so` and `$ objdump -p libsnappy.so` (Dynamic Section: NEEDED...).

Comment: I created the symlink from libsnappy.so to libsnappy.so.1.1.4, still it is failing..
And here is the output of the ldd and objdump commands:
```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff5a3c0000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f1b2cf30000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f1b2cc2e000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1b2c860000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f1b2c64a000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1b2d43d000)
```

Comment: Here is the objdump output:

```
Dynamic Section:
    NEEDED               libstdc++.so.6
    NEEDED               libm.so.6
    NEEDED               libc.so.6
    NEEDED               libgcc_s.so.1
    SONAME               libsnappy.so.1
```

And I see that all the required dependencies are there in /lib64/

Comment: @mazaneicha After installing hadoop client/native libraries and having a 'native' folder in 'plugins.d/<project_custom_folder>/' and creating sym-link to libhadoop.so and libsnappy.so, it is working properly, as native folder is being added to java.library.path automatically in flume-ng. Somehow adding the native folders to LD_LIBRARY_PATH did not work.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the info! For the benefit of others who may struggle with the same issue, you might wanna put this as an answer to your own question.

Comment: Somehow it is not allowing me to post it as Answer, it says I don't have enough permissions and reputations.